# Java methods called from scala run slowly

Tags: java, performance, scala

I have some pre-existing java code which has been compiled to a JAR. This is included in the classpath of a Scala project, and I'm calling some of the java methods from Scala. This is under Java 1.7, Scala 2.11.2 and all within Scala IDE in Eclipse.

Example:

```scala
def step[Ctx] = Locality.stepFn[SubProblemBSolution, Ctx] { (x : SubProblemBSolution) => x.mutate }
```

Here, SubProblemBSolution is a java class with a mutate() method. The rest is Scala. This method is already long-running in java (about 0.5s average over 1000 runs), but when called from Scala it takes around 2.5s to complete.

The jar is not recompiled for scala, I'm just calling the existing compiled classes. I tried decompiling the scala .class files to see if they were calling anything odd, but they just have /*compiled code*/ where the calls to the java code are.

Any idea why this might be running so slowly? Can I do anything to improve the situation?

Thanks.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason at all that it should run slowly as at runtime they are just similar byte code. I suspect when for first time  the class loader loads it and say it loaded some native library, then it might take time for first time usage.

Comment: Try this [java online decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/). Scroll to the bottom of the page until you see "Live Demo".

Comment: You're sure you're passing the same values to the function? Like the same problem to solve?

Comment: How do you measure method run time? There are plenty of tricks to do it properly, so the only easy way to it correctly is to use [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)

Comment: Thanks folks. @ziggystar definitely the same problem to solve. I've also tried a couple of instances of the problem in case it was specific to that one.

Comment: @shutty I'm just using a call to System.currentTime() and compat.Platform.currentTime on either side of the call to mutate(); however as the difference is a couple of seconds it's noticeable just by sight. Thanks for the link though, I'll take a look.

Comment: @Aivean I'll take a look at JD if I don't get anywhere with som-snytt's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

How you are making the call from Scala can matter.

In particular, avoid objects and static initializers. That is, avoid running an expensive computation as part of the constructor for an object, which is run during class initialization. That tends to run deoptimized.

The old issues [here](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3305) and especially [here](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3821) are symptomatic.

Comment: Thanks. This could be the issue. There is some static code which could be avoided, also mutate() creates a copy of x which then has some changes applied before being returned. I'll focus on these and update on progress soon.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat frustratingly this problem was solved by creating a new project in Scala IDE and reimporting everything. Even when then importing this new project into Eclipse the calls to Java methods ran at full speed. I can't see anything obviously different when looking at the two projects (including diff'ing their .classpath and .project files), but there must be something lurking in a config somewhere that's doing it.

I tried removing some static references which did seem to make some improvement as per @som-snytt's answer - but the big difference came from making a new project.